# Search Filter By Fields and Values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have 4 classes:

```
public class Advertise {
    public int AdvertiseId {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    Description
}

public class Fields {
    public int FieldId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class Values {
    public int ValueId {get;set;}
    public string ValueName {get;set;}
}

public class FieldsValues {
    public int FieldValueId {get;set;}
    public int AdvertiseId {get;set;}
    public int FieldId {get;set;}
    public int ValueId {get;set;}
}
```

When user filter the search and submit the form, I get the Request.QueryString["field_"+fieldId] and I do a foreach, like this:

```
var ads = from s in adsViewModel select s;

var fields = Db.Fields.GetAll();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    int fieldValue;
    var requestField = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["field_" + field.FieldId], out fieldValue);

    ads = ads.Where(s => s.FieldsValues.Any(x => x.ValueId == fieldValue));
}
```

Fine it works!

However the result of search only return a ADS, when the fields have exacly criteria. For example:

Ads have 2 fields:

Rooms = 7 (ValueId)

Parking Spaces = 3 (ValueId)

The search only works, if the user select rooms=7 and parking spaces=3

If the user select in filter only rooms=7 the values in the Request are `field_1=7, field_2=0` and the search returns null.

Comment: What are the values in `fields` if you only select one filter value (i.e. is it `[7, 0]`)?

Comment: Yes. 7, 0. field_1=7, field_2=0.

Comment: Then you could test for zero inside the `foreach`, and if so, skip executing the query. (e.g. `if (fieldValue == 0) { continue; }`) Currently, if its zero, `ads = ads.Where(s => s.FieldsValues.Any(x => x.ValueId == 0));` would return no results assuming you do not have any values with `ValueId == 0`

Comment: Thanks dude!! It works!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If one of the values in the Request is zero, then your query would equate to

```
ads = ads.Where(s => s.FieldsValues.Any(x => x.ValueId == 0));
```

which means `ads` would be an empty collection assuming there are no rows in your table with `ValueId == 0`.

You can use an `if` statement to test if any of the values are zero, and if so, skip the query

```
foreach (var field in fields)
{
    int fieldValue;
    var requestField = Int32.TryParse(Request.QueryString["field_" + field.FieldId], out fieldValue);
    if (fieldValue == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }
    ads = ads.Where(s => s.FieldsValues.Any(x => x.ValueId == fieldValue));
}
```